# Whay can't I pass values into these variables

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, scope

I'm using eclipse to build an Android Twitter App
I'm trying to pass values into the variables itemOfClothing, clothingEmotion and "user" but eclipse is not even allowing me to initiate variables with the same names let alone pass values into them.

I get the following errors:

```
Duplicate field TwitterApp.itemOfClothing   
Duplicate field TwitterApp.clothingEmotion  
Duplicate field TwitterApp.user 
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token  
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
```

Can some please help?

```
String itemOfClothing; //Item of clothing sending the message
String clothingEmotion; //Message of clothing
String user; //This comes from twitter sign in process
```

//Examples of what would be passed into the variables!

```
itemOfClothing = "pants";
clothingEmotion = "I'm feeling left in the dark";
user = "stuart";
```

Trying to pass values into `itemOfClothing`, `clothingEmotion` and "user" but it won't let me. I know it's something silly but I don't know why. Can someone give me an answer please?

```
public static String MESSAGE = itemOfClothing +": " + clothingEmotion + "! #" + user + "EmotionalClothing";
```

Comment: What on earth do you mean "it won't let me"?  What won't let you?

Comment: `but it won't let me` - error, exception, message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static variables can only reference other static variables.

```
private static String itemOfClothing; //Item of clothing sending the message
private static String clothingEmotion; //Message of clothing
private static String user; //This comes from twitter sign in process
```

Comment: I've just done as you said but I'm getting exactly the same errors. Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String MESSAGE = itemOfClothing +": " + clothingEmotion + "! #" + user + "EmotionalClothing";
```

Its because

`temOfClothing` , `clothingEmotion` and `user`  are **non-static variables** and you are trying assign it to a `static variable MESSAGE`, thus your compiler complains

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field user

make them static variables and your code would work.

```
static String itemOfClothing = "pants";
    static String clothingEmotion = "I'm feeling left in the dark";
    static String user = "stuart";


    private static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
    private static final String TWITTER_AUTHORZE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
    private static final String TWITTER_REQUEST_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";


    public static String MESSAGE = itemOfClothing +": " + clothingEmotion + "! #" + user + "EmotionalClothing";
```

Comment: @user1048682 no way, cuz i copy pasted your code and its working for me, could you please update your post with what you have tried?? and also specify the compiler errors as well. :)

Comment: Do you want to import the android project and take a look for me. I'm not if it's other things in the project making it fail rather than this chunk of code if that makes sence.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared those variables as member variables, but you are trying to assign a `static` string variable, using a static initializer.

A static initializer can only access static variables or literal values.

What you can do is to declare the variables static:

```
static String itemOfClothing = "pants";
static String clothingEmotion = "I'm feeling left in the dark";
static String user = "stuart";
```

Note that if you don't use static initializers on these variables, they won't have values.  However, if you want to set those values as part of program logic, then either declare the string NOT to be a static string, or use a statement to assign the value that is not an "initializer" (part of the declaration).

either:

```
public String MESSAGE = itemOfClothing +": " + clothingEmotion + "! #" + user + "EmotionalClothing";
```

or:

```
public static String MESSAGE;

//on another line as part of a program, after the variables get values
MESSAGE = itemOfClothing +": " + clothingEmotion + "! #" + user + "EmotionalClothing";
```

Comment: Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Yes, declare the variables as static.

Comment: I've just done as you said but I'm getting exactly the same errors. Thanks you for your help

Comment: You should include in the question the *exact* error that the compiler is producing.